# Заменить буквы на цифры в js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Мне надо поменять все буквы в строке по шаблону из массива. Начал, но не смог продолжить. Был идея перебором все буквы получить, но тогда скорость работы оставляла бы желать лучшего. В это коде я создаю переменную в массиве, в которую и будет записана новая строка:

```
array.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
        arr[i]["__TMP__"] =
            stringTable.indexOf( item["name"].toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() );
    });
```

Можно ли как-то это сделать с помощью `replace`?

template array:

```
stringTable: string[] = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H",
    "I",
    "J",
    "K",
    "L",
    "M",
    "N",
    "O",
    "P",
    "Q",
    "R",
    "S",
    "T",
    "U",
    "V",
    "W",
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z"
];
```

input string: `Tim`
outout string: `019008012` (019- t, 008- i, 012- m)

Comment: обязательно 001 или можно 1?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк обязательно. Для первого символа тоже

Comment: А числа могут быть для замены? Или только буквы? То есть любые символы, кроме цифр?

Comment: @Nikolay ниже написал решение, как я это вижу. Я правильно понял условия задачи?

Comment: @AlexanderBragin в массив `stringTable` по задумке можно будет добавить любой символ и он использоваться для кодирования. То есть символ `A` в массиве будет закодирован как `00` (округляем до трех символов) +  порядковый номер `0`

Comment: @Nikolay понял вас. Решение Grundy хорошее, мне тоже нравится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо массива лучше использовать объект, в этом случае не нужен будет поиск, например

```
{
  "A": "000",
  "B": "001",
  "C": "002",
  "D": "003",
  "E": "004",
  "F": "005",
  "G": "006",
  "H": "007",
  "I": "008",
  "J": "009",
  "K": "010",
  "L": "011",
  "M": "012",
  "N": "013",
  "O": "014",
  "P": "015",
  "Q": "016",
  "R": "017",
  "S": "018",
  "T": "019",
  "U": "020",
  "V": "021",
  "W": "022",
  "X": "023",
  "Y": "024",
  "Z": "025"
}
```

Получение же нужной строки для замены сведется к простому получению свойства:

```
symbolsMap[char.toUpperCase()];
```

Это код можно использовать в функции, передаваемую в метод `replace`

```js
var symbolsMap = {
  "A": "000",
  "B": "001",
  "C": "002",
  "D": "003",
  "E": "004",
  "F": "005",
  "G": "006",
  "H": "007",
  "I": "008",
  "J": "009",
  "K": "010",
  "L": "011",
  "M": "012",
  "N": "013",
  "O": "014",
  "P": "015",
  "Q": "016",
  "R": "017",
  "S": "018",
  "T": "019",
  "U": "020",
  "V": "021",
  "W": "022",
  "X": "023",
  "Y": "024",
  "Z": "025",
  
  "Р": "-11",
  "Ы": "-21",
  "К": "-31"
}

var str = "Tim";
var numbers = str.replace(/./gi,$0=>symbolsMap[$0.toUpperCase()]||$0);
console.log(numbers);

var str = "рык";
var numbers = str.replace(/./gi,$0=>symbolsMap[$0.toUpperCase()]||$0);
console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял вопрос то можно попробовать так.

```js
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}

let input = 'Tim'
let inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
let output = '';
for (let i = 0; i < inputLower.length; i++) {
    output += pad(inputLower[i].charCodeAt(0) - 97, 3);
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Правильно, но нужна зависимость от массива. То есть чтобы в будущем можно было добавить туда символы

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код вышел, используем не массив а charAt + отлавливаем ошибки если пользователь ввел не английские буквы.

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var inputText = (document.querySelector(".text-in").value).toLowerCase();
  var outText = "";
  if (inputText != "") {
    inputText = inputText.split('');
    for (var i = 0, inputTextL = inputText.length; i < inputTextL; i++) {
      var num = (inputText[i].charCodeAt(0)) - 96;
      if (num < 1 || num > 26) {
        document.querySelector(".text-in").value = "English word, please!";
        return;
      }
      if (num < 9) {
        outText = outText + "00" + num;
      } else {
        outText = outText + "0" + num;
      }
    }
    document.querySelector(".text-in").value = outText;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text-in">
<button>Зашифровать</button>
```

Comment: Решение использовать юникод отличное! Но проблема в том, что мне в будущем потребуется добавить в массив помимо английских букв и русские. А может и английские

Comment: Ну хотя если убрать условие, то любой юникод можно получить.. с ним и работать будет быстрей

Comment: @Nilolay функцию достаточно гибкая получилась, и да можно шифровать просто по юникоду, тогда код получается еще лучше. Если вы считаете, что мой ответ решает ваш вопрос, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: завтра протестирую код на те цели, которые мне нужны. Изначально просто задумывалось, что будет ограниченный список символов. Так скорее всего тоже сработает. И даже лучше, я думаю

Answer (score 1):

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(replacement) {
  var _this = this;

  replacement.forEach(function(element, index) {
    var re = new RegExp(element, "gi");

    _this = _this.replace(re, "000".substring(0, "000".length - index.toString().length) + index.toString());
  });

  return _this;
};

var originalString = "Hello Привет 007!!!";
var newString = originalString.replaceAll(['h', 'e', 'l', 'п', 'р', 'и', '!', 'в', 'е', 'т', 'o']);

console.log(originalString + " -> " + newString);
```

---

Для данного кода важно, чтобы среди символов для замены `['h', 'e', 'l', 'п', 'р', 'и', '!', 'в', 'е', 'т', 'o']` не было чисел. Если будут числа — напишите, пожалуйста, вопрос более развернуто со всеми условиями. От этого будет зависить решение.

P.S.: Если будут числа: можно сначала регулярным выражением числа заменить, а потом остальные символы. Потому что, если мы сначала в строке заменим символы, а затем начнем заменять числа — в строке как бы появятся ещё числа...